# is there a way to unlock an android device from a service?

Tags: android, unlock

I have an application in which I need to unlock the phone from a service which searches a backend and if it finds data it turns on the screen.

So far I have not found how to unlock the phone or the answers are very old and do not work.

Comment: Have you discussed your plans with your attorney?